# How to block further ServletContextListeners from running if exception is thrown in one of them?

Tags: java, web-applications, servletcontextlistener

If I have multiple `SerlvetContextListener`s in my web.xml (they run in-order per the spec) how can I stop further listeners from running if the previous one throws an exception?

For example:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>ListenerA</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>ListenerB</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>ListenerC</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I want `ListenerC` to not run at all if `ListenerB` ends up throwing an exception (which will block the whole application from being deployed anyway).

Is there a way to configure this behavior?